# How to plot multiple sub graph using xmgrace in one file

Tags: bash, gnuplot, xmgrace

I want to plot data from multiple files to one page using xmgrace.

Example:

- I have files name a.dat b.dat c.dat with data in two columns.
- Now I want to plot the data from the *.dat files in different sub-plots using xmgrace. The Sub-plot Matrix is shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: I think your question is not related to bash programming, so you better post it in, say, [Superuser](https://superuser.com/). Aside from this: Does [this](http://exciting-code.org/xmgrace-quickstart#toc5) help you with your problem?

Comment: While not a lot of people know this, xmgrace is actually a programming language. This can be solved with batch programing in xmgrace. I strongly vote against closing this question.

Comment: So you want to have a sub-plot for each dataset?

Comment: yes i want plot all data in one file

Comment: And do you want to have this in multiple graphs? You need to be a bit more specific in what you actually want. Could you answer the following questions by [edit]ing your post? **(1)** Can you show us an example how your data looks like? **(2)** Do you want 1 or two graphs or more graphs? **(3)** Which columns from which files should be plotted in which graph? **(4)** Do you want the data to be concatenated? **(5)** can you show us an image of what you potentially would like to have?

Comment: hope all doubts are clear now. please suggest any idea

Comment: You have two columns per file, I assume col1 is X and col2 is Y? do you want a graph per file? or is each file a set that should be printed in a single graph (note, graph is xmgrace nomenclature for a single XY axis-set, in the example above you have 5 graphs; a set is xmgrace nomenclature for a data-plot of data in a graph, i.e. a line in the graph.). Please be very specific.

Comment: Like if u have many data files, the script should plot all the files automatically in rows or columns and per graph should determine per file/data.

Comment: So lets summarize, to be really clear: Given a file with 4 columns, (X,Y1,Y2,Y3), you want an xmgrace-graph with 3 plots of that data file, each additional file should create an additional xmgrace-graph. Is this correct?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].